# Ubutnu 18.04 on XPS15 9500: default gnuplot plots are small (python matplotlib as well)

Tags: display-resolution, xps, gnuplot

The title said it all. I recently installed ubuntu18 in my new xps15 laptop.
Everytime when I plot with gnuplot and matplotlib, the default plots are always very small. Also, when I open gnuplot under ssh the plots are very small, and the fonts as well.

I believe the problem comes from the 4K monitor that the xps15 is having.

I have tryied changing the resolution of the display from 3840 x 2400 to 2048 x 1152,
but nothing much have changed.

Thanks

Comment: In the case of gnuplot, you should be able to set the plot (canvas) size explicitly as part of the `terminal` command - so for the default `wxt` terminal type try something like `set term wxt size 800,600` for example

Comment: this is my temporary solution, but the doing gnuplot under ssh still gives small plots and fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, support for high resolution displays (HiDPI) remains limited in some cases. Modern desktops and applications start to adapt, but older programs may render extremely small on high resolution displays. There is not much else you can do than to run your desktop on HD resolution, i.e. 1920 x 1080 if you need to run these applications.

That said, the more recent your Ubuntu version, the better the support for HiDPI. So you probably should have installed the latest Ubuntu long term release, 20.04, instead of 18.04. Some updates of applications shipped with the newer Ubuntu versions may support HiDPI better.

Comment: I have replaced my 18.04 with ubuntu 20.04. Unfortunately, the problem still persists.

Comment: I know. Some updates of applications shipped with the newer Ubuntu versions may support HiDPI better. But not all.